# Lambda error in code

Tags: java, swing, lambda

```
   public static void buttonAdd(boolean[][] coord) {
    for (int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++) {
            Button square = new Button(coord[col][row]);
            square.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
                if (bombOrNot) { //if bomb is true
                    JOptionPane lose = new JOptionPane();
                    lose.setMessage("You Lose");
                    frame.add(lose);
                    System.exit(0);
                } else { //if bomb is false
                    frame.remove(square);
                }

            frame.add(square);



        }
    }
}
```

This code is not compiling, it seems like there is something wrong with the lambda. It says that the closing bracket for the lambda is expected to be a ")".

Comment: Please post the error output.

Comment: You are missing a closing paren and a semicolon after the lambda.

Comment: Also, please make the example https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The error output is MineBoard.java:61: error: ')' expected
            }
             ^
MineBoard.java:65: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
2 errors

Comment: Yeah, the closing paren for the call `addActionListener((ActionEvent e)` (Note the two opening parens.

Comment: `bombOrNot` is not a good name for a boolean variable, as (assuming it's not a quantum minesweeper) the square contains bomb or the square does not a bomb will always be true.

Comment: What’s the point of adding the `JOptionPane` to the frame when you terminate the entire JVM via `System.exit(0);` before anyone has a chance to see it? Do you actually want to do something like `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(…)`?

Answer (score 2):

The Lambda is passed in a call to the method `addActionListener((ActionEvent e) ->` which has only one argument
meaning that after the Lambda you need `);`  So...

```
public static void buttonAdd(boolean[][] coord) {
    for (int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++) {
            Button square = new Button(coord[col][row]);
            square.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
                if (bombOrNot) { //if bomb is true
                    JOptionPane lose = new JOptionPane();
                    lose.setMessage("You Lose");
                    frame.add(lose);
                    System.exit(0);
                } else { //if bomb is false
                    frame.remove(square);
                }
            }); // <<<<<<<<<    here Note: added } in edit

            frame.add(square);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: still missing a '}'... before the closing ')'

Comment: doing it by eyeball since I am not going to make  self contained for Swing :)

Answer (score 2):

indenting the way the compiler *sees* the indentation of your code and commenting where the error happens (obviously the compiler does not see your code in that way since it get converted to a stream of tokens - without any indentation)

```
// wrong code, just re-indented to clarify
public static void buttonAdd(boolean[][] coord) {
    for (int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++) {
            Button square = new Button(coord[col][row]);
            square.addActionListener(
                (ActionEvent e) -> {
                    if (bombOrNot) { //if bomb is true
                        JOptionPane lose = new JOptionPane();
                        lose.setMessage("You Lose");
                        frame.add(lose);
                        System.exit(0);
                    } else { //if bomb is false
                        frame.remove(square);
                    }
                    frame.add(square);
                }
            }  // missing ) to close addActionListener(
        }
```

since you probably don't want to add square inside the lambda, you should close it '}' and close the `addActionListener` with ');` before that line.

```
        ...
        } else { //if bomb is false
            frame.remove(square);
        }
    } );  // this line is somehow missing in your code
    frame.add(square);
    ...
```

Comment: This is not the way the compiler sees the code. If you replace all sequences of line breaks, spaces and tabs with a single space, you’ll get an idea of how the compiler sees the code…

Comment: @Holger really? do you think that 'notation' would help the OP with his problem? If you want to be pedantic, it is more like (and very abbreviated): the source code is converted into a stream of tokens which then is parsed to create syntax trees; symbols are entered and annotations processed; then the compiler starts analyzing the syntax trees and create the class files. This is based on the OpneJDK compiler - obviously it  also depends on the implementation - and again, probably of no HELP to solve the question. I have edited the answer regarding your concerns...

Comment: I’m not saying that “indenting the way the compiler sees the code” was helpful in any way. I just said, you did not intend that way you said, which might be nitpicking, indeed, but why not saying that you “indented according to the actual logical nesting” or such alike and not discuss the compiler at all?

Comment: @Holger maybe because the OP wrote "This code is not compiling", that is, the compiler is not understanding that code -> so I wanted to show how the compiler is interpreting the code... maybe it is just because I didn't think the OP or someone else would mind I writing it that way... or just because my English is crap, but at least I tried to help...

Comment: and maybe you were successful, who knows. Perhaps the OP comes back one day to acknowledge that. That shouldn’t stop you from improving postings, if you can. Or just leave it, my comment was not supposed to think about it for hours…